# SimpleXML changing parsed decimals

Tags: simplexml

I have this xml file - http://gamebattles.majorleaguegaming.com/ps4/call-of-duty-ghosts/team/ngx2-gaming/stats.xml

here which I am outputting the element "winPercentage" as seen below

```
<?php
$url="http://gamebattles.majorleaguegaming.com/ps4/call-of-duty-ghosts/team/ngx2-gaming/stats.xml";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
?>
<?php echo $xml->currentStats->winPercentage; ?>
```

The question is, how can I change the output of 0.667 to 66.7 instead? I assume it would involve multiplying it by 100, but have no idea how to achieve this.

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is below for anyone else looking for the same thing

Replace:

```
<?php echo $xml->currentStats->winPercentage; ?>
```

With

```
<?php echo (float)$xml->currentStats->winPercentage *100; ?>
```